# Datatable is not updated after actionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I'm facing some problem updating my dataTable when I perform a filter operation with this:

```
<p:panel styleClass="card" header="Filtri">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid"
                            styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="orderMinFilter" label="N. bolla più basso"
                                    value="#{productionOrdersView.orderNumberStartFilter}">
                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:outputLabel for="orderMinFilter" value="N. bolla più basso" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="orderMaxFilter" label="N. bolla più alto"
                                    value="#{productionOrdersView.orderNumberEndFilter}">

                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:outputLabel for="orderMaxFilter" value="N. bolla più alto" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancella filtri" icon="ui-icon-clear"
                                styleClass="red-btn flat"
                                actionListener="#{productionOrdersView.clearFilter()}"
                                style="width:auto;margin-bottom:10px; float:right;"
                                update="dtOrders" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cerca" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                styleClass="primary-btn flat"
                                actionListener="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}"
                                update="dtOrders"
                                style="width:auto;margin-bottom:10px; float:right;" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
```

This is my dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtOrders" var="productionOrder"
                        value="#{productionOrdersView.orders}" selectionMode="single"
                        reflow="true" selection="#{productionOrdersView.selected}"
                        filteredValue="#{productionOrdersView.filtered}"
                        widgetVar="ordersTable" rowKey="#{productionOrder.pk}"
                        emptyMessage="Nessun elemento oppure la ricerca è ancora attiva..."
                        paginator="true" rows="20">
```

And this is the method:

```
public void filter() {
    if (orderNumberStartFilter != null && orderNumberEndFilter != null) {
        this.orders = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter),
                Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter));
        this.filtered = orders;
    }
}
```

The filter() method is executed correctly and the list in the bean are correct (I search for 11 elements and I got it), but the dataTable is updated but not with these values; why? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You add form tag to update property of commandButton.

```
  <p:commandButton value="Cerca" icon="ui-icon-search"
                            styleClass="primary-btn flat"
                            actionListener="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}"
                            update=":formName:dtOrders"
                            style="width:auto;margin-bottom:10px; float:right;" />
```

.

Comment: It doesn't change! The fact that if I price once and then once the table is updated correctly!

Comment: Did you check your query? If it works one field(price) , it should be work with other fields.

Comment: The jpql query is ok! The fact that if I click twice on the button the table is correctly updated, whereas with one nope. Why?